# Wrap element which have an input element

Tags: jquery

How do I wrap an element which have an input element

in this case, i want to wrap `<td>` tag.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <th>
     <td>
       <input type="text">wrap me please</input>
     </td>
     <td>
        don't wrap me
     </td>
  </th>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My existing jQuery `$('tbody tr td').wrap('<div class="single-field"></div>');`

Comment: isn't it invalid markup? and you also want to get invalid markup. element under `td` should be wrapped.

Comment: You're right @Jai, it broke the table layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input').closest('td').wrap('<div/>');
```

Will wrap the `td` that has a input as a descendent with a div tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').parent().wrap(element);
```

or you want it to work only in specific area like div or a table.

```
$('table > input').parent().wrap(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('td').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('input'))
        {
            $(this).find('input').wrap('<div id="wrapper" />')
        }
    });
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/uywmm/